# How to execute 'bat' as a local user in Jenkins - Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, windows

I have to create a Pipeline from the Jenkins 'master' which execute a batch as a specific user on a slave machine.

In the following example:
The slave machine is identified as '**my_node**'. Jenkins 'master' contains a username/password credential called '**my_id**'. I pass the credentials to my batch with the variables **$USER** and **$USERPASS**

```
node('my_node') {
   stage("exec") {
      withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my_id', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'USERPASS')]) {
         bat "runas /savecred /user:MY_DOMAIN\\$USER /password:$USERPASS \"cmd\""
      }
   }
}
```

But when I execute the pipeline, the result are the following:

```
C:\my_workspace>runas /savecred /user:MY_DOMAIN\**** /password:**** "cmd" 
Enter the password for MY_DOMAIN\****: 
script returned exit code 1
```

It is possible to override the password prompt during the pipeline execution ?

Comment: I believe this question better fits either devops or superuser community.

Comment: Thanks, i will duplicate this question in 'devops' community

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've been in same situation.

Answer (score -1):

I do also have same issue any inputs appreciated.

My case is running BDD test cases as part of Pipeline

node('my_node') {
stage("exec") {
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my_id', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'USERPASS')]) {

```
     bat "%NUGET_PACKAGES%/nunit.consolerunner/3.11.1/tools/nunit3-console.exe"
  }
```

}
}

i should run bat "%NUGET_PACKAGES%/nunit.consolerunner/3.11.1/tools/nunit3-console.exe with different user.
Thanks

Comment: Please do not post "I'm having a similar issue" questions as an answer. You could ask this as a separate question with a link to the original question and an explanation of how your problem is different, or you could upvote the original question. Please see https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for more information.